# Cannot login: Failed to start Login Service

Tags: systemd, logind

I've got a VirtualBox instance of Oracle Linux 7.2 which won't start because of `Failed to start Login Service`. On the booting sequence the process hangs on this message and doesn't continue, so I can't even log in and execute `systemctl status systemd-logind.service`.

The probable cause for this is, that I removed zsh while all my users (including root) have zsh set as the default shell (duh!). After that the machine started and I got to the login prompt, but I couldn't login since the shell couldn't be found. I then inserted a Live CD and went into `/etc/passwd` to change the default shell for users to `/bin/bash`. After this the login service won't start at all. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found out that after changing `/etc/passwd` it didn't have the right SELinux settings anymore. I don't really need SELinux on my machine so I solved the problem by disabling SELinux altogether. This is easily done by modifying the file `/etc/selinux/config` and setting the option `SELINUX=permissive` (if you want to keep SELinux file labeling to enable it later) or `SELINUX=disabled` (turning it off completely).

Comment: This failure also occurs when changing the root password from single boot recovery mode.

Comment: Setting it to `disabled` worked for me, but not `permissive`, cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this today with CentOS 7.2 on VirtualBox. I was able to `ssh` in as a regular user and issued

```
touch /.autorelabel
```

Then rebooted to reset all contexts. It takes a while to boot, but worked.

Answer (score 1):

After using `chage` in single user mode because of expired password, it is required to boot with `SELINUX=permissive` set in `/etc/selinux/config` to restore proper labels.

Get proper SELinux context for each modified file from a sane system with `ls -Z /etc/passwd /etc/shadow` and apply context back to broken system.

As an **example**, here are set of commands used on a CentOS 7 after `chage` - **DO NOT APPLY** without comparison from a sane system (test or preproduction) !

```
chcon system_u:object_r:passwd_file_t:s0 /etc/passwd
chcon system_u:object_r:passwd_file_t:s0 /etc/group
chcon system_u:object_r:shadow_t:s0 /etc/shadow
chcon system_u:object_r:shadow_t:s0 /etc/gshadow
```

Review SELinux context of any file you have modified in single mode, before rebooting with `SELINUX=enforcing` to get back to normal operations.

Other ways to copy SELinux context is available at [How to copy SELinux context from one directory and apply it to another directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/354517/23467)

Comment: or more conveniently, run `restorecon` or `fixfiles restore` on `/etc/passwd`.  If there are more files - e.g. `/etc/passwd-` - mislabelled, it's more comprehensive to just run `fixfiles restore`.  Or, `fixfiles onboot` and reboot; this can theoretically be more reliable.

Comment: Thanks. I still have to learn more about SELinux...