# How to copy SELinux context from one directory and apply it to another directory?

Tags: centos, rhel, selinux

How can I copy SELinux context from one directory and apply it to another?

Example use scenario is when creating a new local user outside of the default /home path, like this:

```
$ sudo useradd -d /websites Tim
```

This creates Tim's home directory `/websites` and sets correct permissions and ownership for Tim, however its SELinux context is different from other users, as seen here:

```
# ls -dZ /websites
drwx------. Tim Tim system_u:object_r:etc_runtime_t:s0 /websites
```

What I want to do is copy the SELinux context from an other user's /home directory and apply it to Tim's `/websites` directory.

Other user's SELinux context is like this:

```
# ls -Z /home/
drwx------. Ben  Ben  unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t:s0 Ben
drwx------. Bob  Bob  unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t:s0 Bob
drwx------. lexy lexy unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t:s0 lexy
```

Comment: This is simply done using the `-e` flag as in. `semanage fcontext -a -e /home/Ben '/websites(/.*)?'`  After that you'd have to run `restorecon as in `restorecon -vvRF /websites`  and the new file context will be applied.

Comment: Cheers @val0x00ff - Using equivalence seems a reasonable way of duplicating SELinux contexts.  If you add this as answer and note the switches I will accept it.  The -w switch on `retorecon` appears to be a typo btw.

Comment: @ Alxs, it's a `v` twice which denodes verbosity and I added this as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for that @val0x00ff.  I think I'm finally due for some reading glasses. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is simply done using the `-a` and `-e` flags as in:

```
semanage fcontext -a -e /home/Ben '/websites(/.*)?'
```

`-a` : add,

`-e` : equivalence

---

After that you'd have to run restorecon as in:

```
restorecon -vvRF /websites
```

and the new file context will be applied.

`-v` : show changes in file labels,

`-R` : recursive,

`-F` : force reset of context

---

It is also possible to change the SELinux file context with:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t '/website(/.*)?'
```

This will assign the new filecontext regardless.

`-a` : add,

`-t` : type