# can't boot Linux due to Login service failing to start

Tags: linux-mint, boot, systemd, avahi, logind

I am having a bit of trouble with my linux mint 18.3 (based on Ubuntu 16.04) since I can't manage to properly boot it on my computer.
I have a dual-boot and windows launch properly, so there is that.

I used grub to boot Linux after switching `quiet splash` to `nomodeset` in the boot command and I got those errors :
[image: top quality picture, isn't it ?]

I used this good old google to get some info and the only things I could find didn't really help me solve my problems.
[Someone had conflict with SELinux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321038/cannot-login-failed-to-start-login-service) and it is not installed on my computer.

I also tried to check systemctl status *** but ctrl+alt+F1 doesn't give me any shell prompt. Even in recovery mode, I can only access the root shell prompt before the system tries to boot, once the failure occurs, the shell prompt becomes unavailable for some reasons.

I did manage to get a tty1 by using upstart, so I have access to my drive (and I am currently saving my files on a remote server before performing anymore tinkering) but the tty interface is not really the most user-friendly interface to work with, especially since I am usually working with software such as Qgis. (I am making maps)

Can I do anything to get my computer to boot properly ?
I would rather do this than reinstalling Linux.

thank you for reading.

Comment: From the `tty` try: `systemctl isolate graphica.target` after logging in. That's a command to manually start a graphical session. If it doesn't succeed, maybe there will be some useful debugging output.

Comment: "I can only access the root shell prompt before the system tries to boot " How can you get shell before the system boot? "I did manage to get a tty1 by using upstate" Upstate?

Comment: 18.3 is bugged, nothing but problems, reinstall previous version. they really dropped the ball with that release.

Comment: I might just reinstall, yeah. I'll probably get back to a previous more stable version.